# Where should DTO be defined for a interface?

Tags: c#, interface

I am trying to understand using interfaces to help layer a solution. I have a project within the solution that defines the interface. Then I have a second project that defines a new class that uses the interface defined in the first project.

**The interface:**

```
public interface IDocumentStore
{
    Case GetCaseByAccount(int accountId);
}
```

Using the above example where should I define the return class "Case"? Should it be defined in the interface project as a class? Or should it be defined as an interface too?

Most examples I've seen only return simple types, i.e. string, int, bool, so it is unclear to me where this class should be defined.

The interface will be used in the future for creating other Document Store providers.

Comment: `Case` needs to be defined in the same project as the `IDocumentStore` interface (or at least in a project that is referenced from this project), regardless of whether it's defined as an interface type or a class. It's perfectly fine for an interface to define methods that return concrete types.

Comment: There is a lot of opinion here, personally I have a separate project (or namespace) for models where I would put things that need to be referenced by both the interface and the implementation.

Comment: Frequently you would define the type `Case` in the same project as the interface `IDocumentStore`. You could also define type `Case` in a project that is referenced by the project where `IDocumentStore` is defined.

Comment: See similar question on SE - [should I create interfaces for data transfer objects](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/185636/should-i-create-interfaces-for-data-transfer-objects)

Comment: To avoid tight coupling (meaning making interface IX depend on a fixed class Y) you can use `ICase GetCaseByAccount(int accountId)`, and then have class Case implement ICase. I can't think of many reasons not to do it.

Comment: Unless you're really strict with this, you're going to end out with circular project references: if the interface project references the class project, then the class project can't reference the interface project..

Comment: @PeterB How many DTOs will you have that implement the same class? Interfaces for DTOs make no sense, it's completely overengineering

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I've done it multiple times, for good reasons and with clear benefits in those situations. YMMV

Comment: Of course, if you love creating 8 files for each new feature...